# What object handles switching views in a desktop MVC app?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, desktop-application

In a desktop application that uses MVC, what object should be responsible for switching from one view to another? A controller at the next highest level of abstraction?

(Conceptual question not particular to language/platform.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would be correct.  You can think of your controller as something of a traffic cop.  It handles directing the incoming traffic through the appropriate channels (your business services), and then directs it to its next destination (the view).